# How can I redefine multiplication this way?

Tags: matrix, pattern-matching, arithmetic

I want the product of matrix objects to be evaluated to the matrix object of dot products of the arguments, but only if the matrices commute. Why this does not work?

```
Unprotect[Times];
Matrix[x_] Matrix[y_] ^= Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x  ;
Protect[Times];
```

Comment: This does not work because "Matrix" is not a defined word. A 2D e.g. matrix is written {{x11,x12},{x21,x22}}

Comment: @DanielHuber yes, it is not a defined symbol, but I want it behave this way.

Comment: It is not necessary to `Unprotect` and `Protect` `Times`. Use `TagSetDelayed` rather than `TagSet`. `Matrix /: Matrix[x_] * Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x.y] /; x.y == y.x;`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define "Matrix" as a new Atom, your approach works.

E.g. let us define matrices a0 and a1 that commute:

```
a0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
a1 = a0 . a0;
```

and also a matrix that does not commute:

```
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
```

If we now define "Matrix":

```
Clear[Matrix]
Unprotect[Times];
Matrix[x_] Matrix[y_] /; x . y == y . x ^= Matrix[x . y];
Protect[Times];
```

We get for the product of 2 commuting matrices:

```
Matrix[a0] Matrix[a1]
(* Matrix[{{0.090018, -0.15005}, {-0.276659, 0.0619167}}] *)
```

and for non-commuting matrices:

```
Matrix[a0] Matrix[b]
(* Matrix[{{-0.725916, -0.626387}, {-0.553722, -0.871338}}] \
Matrix[{{0.114884, -0.425647}, {-0.784798, 0.0351695}}] *)
```

Comment: Oh, I had wron order in the condition, thanks!